# Trying to flash a message raises an exception

Tags: python, flask

I want to use `flash` to show a message, but doing so raises an exception.  The code below demonstrates the error, and works fine if the call to `flash` is removed.  How do I fix this error?

```
from flask import Flask, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('Entered')
    return 'Completed'

app.run(debug=True)
```

```
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you have not set a secret key, so the session is unavailable.  The session relies on a secret key to sign the cookie prevent tampering.  Message flashing relies on the session.

Set the `SECRET_KEY` config item to fix this error.

```
# set as part of the config
SECRET_KEY = 'many random bytes'

# or set directly on the app
app.secret_key = 'many random bytes'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your run.py file

```
from tc import app
app.secret_key='12345'
app.run(debug=True)
```